# Reader loop doesn't work with parameter in string

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, parameters, sqldatareader

I'm trying to display account balance from database in different currencies. Based on comboBox index the currencyValue changes. The problem is that with the parameter currencyValue in query string program never enters the while (reader.Read()) loop. Only with parameter. When I just use magical number for example 4.30 in string instead, it works perfectly fine, but with parameter which value is set to 4.30 nothing happens (only works with 1).

```
private void btnWybierz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fullname = cmbKonto.Text;

        string query = string.Format("SELECT CAST(balance / '{0}' AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) " +
                                            "FROM dbo.Accounts " +
                                            "WHERE (firstname + ' ' + lastname)='{1}'", currencyValue, fullname);

        using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectToDB.ConnectDB())
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            saldo = reader[0];
                            tbSaldo.Text = saldo.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _balance / '{0}'_ are you dividing a number by a string?

Comment: Also you are not using any _parameter_ here. You are just concatenating strings together. Very bad idea from a security point of view. Search about Sql Injection and use _real_ parameters

Comment: If your database has two "John Smiths", one is always going to get the wrong account information.

Comment: And let see what happens when you have a _Mike O'Brian_

Answer (score 4):

This problem may be solved by writing decimal places as 4/30.

This problem may be solved writing Replace '{0}' with {0}